# Why does PHP setcookie work on localhost but not in the browser?

Tags: php, cookies, localhost, webserver

I've created a cookie for my website to store the user's language choice. It works fine on localhost. But after uploading the website to my webspace, the cookie never gets set by any browser I tested (Firefox, Chrome, Opera).

The cookie gets set before any `html` or `echo`, before the `DOCTYPE` opening tag. There are only some `PHP` variable declarations above it.
The cookie expires after 24h. Setting a longer expiration date didn't help, either. 
I also replaced `'/'` with my URL, like `('mysite.de')`, which had no effect. 
I made sure my browsers accept cookies.

This is my `PHP` code:

```
// --- TRANSLATION ---
require_once 'i18n.class.php';
$i18n = new i18n('lang/lang_{LANGUAGE}.ini', 'langcache/', 'de');
$i18n->setForcedLang('de');

// get language cookie
if (isset($_COOKIE['language']) && $_COOKIE['language']== "lang-de") {
  // set language to German
  $i18n->setForcedLang('de');

} elseif (isset($_COOKIE['language']) && $_COOKIE['language']== "lang-en") {
  // set language to English
  $i18n->setForcedLang('en');
}

// language buttons & set cookie
if(isset($_GET['lang'])) {
  $lang=$_GET['lang'];
  if ($lang == 'de') {
    $i18n->setForcedLang('de');
    setcookie('language', 'lang-de', time() + 86400, '/');
  }
  if ($lang == 'en') {
    $i18n->setForcedLang('en');
    setcookie('language', 'lang-en', time() + 86400, '/');
  }
}

$i18n->init();
?>
```

This is the correlating `HTML` (the buttons to choose a language):

```
<div class="language">
  <a href="?lang=de" name="lang-de" class="lang-de">DE</a>/
  <a href="?lang=en" name="lang-en" class="lang-en">EN</a>
</div>
```

Why does my code work fine on localhost, but not on the web server? Help on what is going wrong here is much appreciated.

EDIT:
I tested some more with a PHP file with just the cookie code I've shown:

Setting `$i18n->setForcedLang('');` works and `$_GET['lang']` returns the correct language, depending on what button got clicked. Really only `setcookie('language', 'lang-de', time() + 86400, '/');` (or `'lang-en'`)seems to get ignored by the browser if I'm running the code via web server.

Answer (score 0):

If your website does not have SSL certificate, then you should make sure this PHP option below is set to 0.

```
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', '0');
```

Additional recommended settings:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', '0');
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', '1');
```

Comment: My test webspace doesn't have SSL. But I always use SSL for officially published sites. I tested my code with and without SSL, but it gets set in neither case when run by the server. The server is run by my webspace provider, not myself. Could I set your suggestions via .htaccess? I will look into this more, though.